# haproxy ingress forward request to service based on header check

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, haproxy, haproxy-ingress

We have a ingress and service like below, I want the request to be handle by my-ingress  only if request path starts with /api and has "Authorization" header. if condition is met then forward request to internal-service. if the request path starts with /api and doesn't contain "Authorization" header then request should be forwarded to external-service.

I am trying to use config-backend annotation in ingress like

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/config-backend: >
  acl has_auth_header hdr(Authorization) -m found  
  http-request deny if !has_auth_header
```

With above annotation I can see the request getting denied if Authorization header is not passed.
I am not sure if I can achieve the behavior I described above using this config-backend annotation (https://haproxy-ingress.github.io/v0.12/docs/configuration/keys/#configuration-snippet) or any other approach at ingress level. I also tried having 2 ingress one having condition like process only if has_auth_header which forward request to internal-service

```
    ingress.kubernetes.io/config-backend: |
      acl has_auth_header hdr(Authorization) -m found  
      http-request deny if has_auth_header
```

and another like process only if !has_auth_header which forward request to external-service, no luck.

I am new to kubernetes/haproxy, so would appreciate any help/pointer please. thanks.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: some-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "haproxy"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/timeout-connect: "30s"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/timeout-http-request: "15m"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/timeout-server: "15m"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "*.some.domain.com"
      secretName: "some-certificate"
  rules:
    - host: "*.some.domain.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /api
            backend:
              service:
                name: internal-service
                port:
                  number: 10000
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-service
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: some-application-to-route-request.com
```

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).